# Visual Studio 2012 Add New Items Scrambled

Tags: visual-studio-2012

At the moment I can not add anything new to my visual studio project because when I try I get this random jumble. I tried reinstalling Visual Studio to no avail and even a system reset didn't fix it. I was wondering if anyone has any possible solutions to this problem...
[image]

Comment: Looks more like a graphics driver problem - have you tried reinstalling the latest driver for your graphics card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a GPU-acceleration GUI glitch.  You can disable acceleration by going to TOOLS/Options - unclick "automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and disable both sub-options.

Or you can try updating your graphics driver for your system as Roger Rowland suggested in the comment to your question.